# Migrating MyISAM tables from 5.5 => 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, myisam, upgrade, mysql-5.6

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers on migrating MyIASM tables from mysql 5.5 to 5.6, specifically using Percona builds, via an rsync?

Is this safe?

I know we need to do a full mysqldump/reload for a migration for InnoDB tables but I didn't see any notes about significant changes to the MyISAM format between the two.

It would make things a little nicer for a rather large MyISAM db that would take several days to complete with a mysqldump.

Comment: So, you want to move the MyISAM tables apart from the move of the InnoDB tables ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyISAM didn't change between 5.5 and 5.6. It's not being developed, and it's virtually stagnant.

Use `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` and then it's safe to copy the MyISAM tables. This is mentioned in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/backup-methods.html

Other solutions:

- [mysqldump --tab](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab) outputs tab-delimited data files instead of SQL, so it's much faster to import with [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html).
- [mysqlhotcopy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) does a physical copy of MyISAM tables (it doesn't work for InnoDB tables). But be careful because mysqlhotcopy is [on the chopping block for deprecation](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/04/17/proposal-to-deprecate-mysqlhotcopy.html).
- [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper), which dumps to SQL, but it supports compression and multi-threaded execution for both dump and restore. Unfortunately it does not support an option like `--tab`.